# iOS reads some characters oddly?

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsurl

In my iOS app, I'm downloading images from a server. For every image on the server, I take it's URL (path), log it, then add it into an array. My problem is that one image on the server has quotation marks in the file name itself. So, when I log the URL like this:

```
NSLog(@"New file path reads: %@", /*path on server*/);
```

The log output reads:

> New file path reads: http://server.com/folder/\"Image\".jpeg

This is expected because the (\") escape code returns the character (") and and the file downloads fine. Next, I'm using the file's path to create an NSString to display the name of the file. I do this by simply replacing the occurrence of "http://server.com/folder/" in the file name string. For all other files, this works perfectly, e.g. if I have a file at the path:

> http://server.com/folder/Test.jpeg

The new display name would read:

> Test.jpeg

However, when the file name/path has quotes in it (like "Image".jpeg), the display name reads:

> %5c%22Image%5c%22.jpeg

So, my question is: why is the display name different than the URL I log when all I do is replace the occurrence of "http://server.com/folder/" and how can I fix this?

Any help would be really appreciated, I've looked everywhere for an answer but couldn't find anything useful!

**UPDATE**: I just realized this happens with lots of characters (<, >, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is URL encoding. You can get what you want like this:

```
[encodedString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you most likely want to use the `NSURL` method `-lastPathComponent`. It will pull apart the URL properly for you, and perform unescaping as part of the process.